# MongoDB Panache Best Practices for Multi-Document Transactions

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

Regarding the quote below in the MongoDB Panache documentation [https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache]

> MongoDB offers ACID transactions since version 4.0. MongoDB with Panache doesn’t provide support for them.

As such, is there a recommended approach or a best practice on handling Multi-Document transactions to ensure atomicity?

Consider the example:

```
public void buyCarTest() {   
    carRepository.increaseStock(1); 
    cashRepository.decreaseCash(10000);
}
```

If we were to do it manually, it would be:

1. check if the write operation into 2nd repository failed, and
2. if so, revert changes made in `carRepository`

This approach seems tenuous at best especially if there are more than 2 repositories I'm writing into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose is what is called a compensation and it is tricky to implements.

I'd rather use an event based mechanism for this: you send the two events and asynchronously they are processed so a failure of one of the tenant (the stock manager) will not impact the second one.

You can also use MongoDB transaction but for this you will need to use the MongoDB API instead of Panache (so get the collection from your entity and use it).

Transaction support for MongoDB is a work in progress (see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/7222) you can watch this issue to be notified when it'll be implemented.